# Spliting a variable into multiple in SAS

Tags: sas

I was wondering if it is possible to split a variable in to multiple variables. I have a big variable I would like to split into multiple columns.

```
"0060175052";"Three Chords and the Truth: Hope, Heartbreak, and Changing Fortunes in Nashville";"Laurence Leamer";"1997","Harpercollins"
```

I would like to split it where the semicolons are. So:

```
v1 = "0060175052"
v2 = "Three Chords and the Truth: Hope, Heartbreak, and Changing Fortunes in 
      Nashville"
v3 = "Laurence Leamer"
v4 = "1997"
v5 = "Harpercollins"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sofie:

How you split the value depends on where it is coming from.

### Reading a data file

For the case of reading a text file with an INPUT statement you indicate the delimiter in the INFILE statement, for example:

```
INFILE *input-file* DSD DLM=';';
```

### Parsing a data value

For the case of a variable in an existing data set the SCAN function can extract different parts of a string.

```
v1 = SCAN (big_variable, 1, ';');
...
v5 = SCAN (big_variable, 5, ';');
```

If the big variable values can contain consecutive semi-colons that indicate a blank value you will need to use the M modifier in the modifiers argument. For example:

```
v1 = SCAN (big_variable, 1, ';', 'M');
```

For only five parts you probably don't need to array-ify the process.  If the string has many parts to split, an array would by used to reduce coding repetition:

```
attrib v1-v20 length=$200;
array v v1-v20;
do index = 1 to dim(v);
  v(index) = SCAN (big_variable, index, ';');
end;
```

More advanced scanning techniques would use Perl regular expressions as surfaced by the SAS PRX* call routines and functions -- such as PRXPARSE, PRXMATCH, PRXNEXT, etc...